# Associative array passing and accessing in PHP

Tags: php

I am facing a problem. Here i an associative array names **$arr** . I passed this through input. After submitting form when I want to access it shows me  **Undefined index: paper** . here is my php code. I also tried to solve this last night but can't. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
   $arr = array('book' => '20' ,'pen' => '10' ,'paper' => '50' , );

   if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
       $new_arr = $_POST['arr2'];
       echo $new_arr['paper'];
     }
?>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <br><br>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $arr ?>" name="arr2"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: How can you `echo` an `array` in php?? You've to encode the array in json format.

Comment: use `arr2[]` in `input name` like `name='arr2[]'`

Comment: thanks. i did that. it does not give me expected value

Comment: Do you want `50` by input `paper` ?

Comment: exactly............

Comment: i think you should process the input on the server side instead put it into html, and then in the backend you could make array list to check if the input have some keys on it, you get the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple. First encode the array to store inside single element in form of text and then decode the same value.

```
<?php
   $arr = json_encode(array('book' => '20' , 'pen' => '10' , 'paper' => '50'));
   if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
       $new_arr = json_decode($_POST['arr2'], TRUE);
       echo $new_arr['book'];
       echo $new_arr['pen'];
       echo $new_arr['paper'];
   }
?>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" value='<?php echo $arr; ?>' name="arr2"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I am coming bask within 30 minutes.

Comment: It works properly. There is a problem on single quotation on **value= ' '** attribute . I did that double. anyways thanks....

Answer (score 0):

First put array as as json

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo json_encode($arr) ?>" name="arr2"><br>
```

You need to provide key in `$arr`, like below

```
<?php
   $arr = array('book' => '20' ,'pen' => '10' ,'paper' => '50');

   if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
       $new_arr = json_decode($_POST['arr2'],true);
       echo $new_arr['paper'];
   }
?>
```

Comment: provide value as `paper` here `value="<?php echo $arr ?>"` in input

Comment: Actually i want to pass that array($arr) . and want to access.

Comment: I am coming bask within 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

`echo $arr` will just produce 'Array' so it won't help you. But you can use `serialize` and `unserialize`:

```
<?php
   $arr = array('book' => '20' ,'pen' => '10' ,'paper' => '50' , );

   if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
       $new_arr = unserialize($_POST['arr2']);
       echo $new_arr['paper'];
     }
?>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <br><br>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo serialize($arr) ?>" name="arr2"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: thanks but it shows me **unserialize(): Error at offset 5 of 9 bytes**

Comment: So, what **exactly** does the error contain? As you can see on https://3v4l.org/VQuVR, the given array does not produce such a message

Comment: I am coming bask within 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

use for loop for `input hidden` pass name as `array key`

```
<?php
   $arr = array('book' => '20' ,'pen' => '10' ,'paper' => '50' , );

   if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
       $new_arr = $_POST['paper'];
       //print_r($new_arr);
       echo $new_arr;
     }
?>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <br><br>
    <?php foreach($arr as $k=>$v){
       ?>
      <input type="text" value="<?php echo $v ?>" name="<?php echo $k?>"><br>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I am coming bask within 30 minutes.